# Value is not changing in real time -- VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using a JS class, I have following code:

```
class Field {
    public Value = null;
    public Items = [];
    public UniqueKey = null;

    public getItems() {
        let items = [...this.Items];
        items = items.filter((item) => {
            if (item.VisibleIf) {
                const matched = item.VisibleIf.match(/\$\[input:(.*?)\]/g);
                if (matched?.length) {
                    const srv = Service.getInstance();
                    for (let match of matched) {
                        match = match.slice(8, -1);
                        if (srv.Fields?.length) {
                            let found = srv.Fields.find((x) => x.UniqueKey === match);
                            if (found) {
                                item.VisibleIf = item.VisibleIf.replace(
                                    `$[input:${match}]`,
                                    found.Value ?? ''
                                );
                                return JSON.parse('' + eval(item.VisibleIf));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
        return items;
    }

    public getInputTitle() {
        let title = this.Title;
        const matched = title.match(/\$\[input:(.*?)\]/g);
        if (matched?.length && title) {
            const srv = Service.getInstance();
            for (let match of matched) {
                match = match.slice(8, -1);
                if (srv.Fields?.length) {
                    let found = srv.Fields.find((x) => x.UniqueKey === match);
                    if (found) {
                        title = title.replace(`$[input:${match}]`, found.Value ?? '');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

Now I have a Vue component:

```
<div v-for="Field in Fields" :key="Field.UniqueKey">
    <v-select
        v-if="Field.Type == 'Select'"
        :label="Field.getInputTitle()"
        v-model="Field.Value"
        :items="Field.getItems()"
        item-text="Value"
        item-value="Id"
    />
    <v-input
        v-else-if="Field.Type == 'Input'"
        v-model="Field.Value"
        :label="Field.getInputTitle()"
    />
</div>

// JS
const srv = Service.getInstance();
Fields = srv.getFields(); // <- API call will be there.
```

So basically, data comes from an API, having Title as `Input $[input:uniqueKey]`, in a component I am looping over the data and generating the fields. See `getInputTitle` function in `Field` class, it works very well. All the fields which are dependent on the `$[input:uniqueKey]` are changing when I start typing into that field on which other fields are dependent.

Now I have pretty much same concept in the `getItems` function, so basically, what I want to do is whenever I type into a field and that field exists in the `VisibleIf` on the `Items`, the `VisibleIf` will be like `'$[input:uniqueKey] < 1'`, or any other valid JavaScript expression which can be solved by `eval` function. But the `getItems` function is called only 1st time when page gets loaded, on the other hand the `getInputTitle` function which is pretty much same, gets called every time when I type into the field.

I tried to explain at my best, I will provide any necessary information if needed.

Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the `Object` itself in here:

```
item.VisibleIf = item.VisibleIf.replace( `$[input:${match}]`, found.Value ?? '' );
```

Even though you tried to copy the array, but you have done shallow copy of the object in here: `let items = [...this.Config.Items];`

I suggest the following solution:

```
const visibleIf = item.VisibleIf.replace(
    `$[input:${match}]`,
    found.Value ?? ''
);
const val = '' + helpers.evalExp('' + visibleIf);
if (helpers.isJSON(val)) {
    return JSON.parse(val);
}
```

Means instead of changing the `VisibleIf` object, just store it into the variable and just use that.

I hope that it will fix your issue. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Let me give it a try.

Comment: Man you just saved my day. Thanks for this awesome solution.

Comment: Glad it helped ;)